# 特定の人が作成した、特定の文字列をレポジトリから検索するには？

Tags: git

巨大なレポジトリの中で、現在の revision の中にある、ある人が作成したソースコード中の「FIXME」という文字列を、すべて探したいとします。
この文字列自体はあちこちで使われていて、普通に grep をかけても膨大な数の候補が表示されていまいます。

これを見つける方法はありますでしょうか。

Comment: ある人が書き加えたFIXMEのうち、現在まで残っているもの、ということでしょうか？単純で強引な方法としては、全ファイルをblameして、コミッタとキーワードでgrepとか…。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 単純で強引な方法としては、全ファイルをblameして、コミッタとキーワードでg‌​repとか…。

をコマンドで書くと

```
for i in `git ls-files`
do
    git --no-pager blame -f "$i" | grep 'USERNAME' | grep 'FIXME'
done
```

でできると思います。

Comment: 言い出しっぺとして補足しておくと、blameで現れるのはその行を変更したと思われるコミットなので、関係ない変更（インデントの変更、前後の行の変更など）に巻き込まれた場合正しく抽出できません。